# Triggering a method after transaction commits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  do_this
  Something.after_commit.action
  do_that
end
# Something.action is fired/run in case no exceptions in transaction
```

How can one achieve this?

NOTE: one doesn't see where the transaction starts and ends (I mean `transaction do` and `end`)

Comment: [ar_after_transaction](https://github.com/grosser/ar_after_transaction)

Answer (score -2):

You must use this pattern, with the `save!` (that raises exception on error):

```
begin
  do_this_before_update_the_db
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    update_1_db_if_no_fails
    update_2_db_if_no_fails
    ...
    update_n_db_if_no_fails
  end
  DO-THIS-AFTER-COMMIT-ONLY-IF-NO-EXCEPTIONS
rescue Exception => exception
  do_this_if_some_update_fails # depending on the exception you must raise again from here.
ensure
  do_this_always_fail_or_no # this runs after commit
end
```

You can't put `after_commit` inside the transaction, because this run inside the transaction, before the commit is done.

All that is inside the transaction block runs with one commit at the end of the block. All callbacks runs inside this transaction. And all indented transactions runs inside this transaction (with only one commit). You can found detailed information [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-transaction).

You must see that at the log, with only one commit at the end.

Also you can have this pattern on `update_2_db_if_no_fails`, with an ensure block that runs always fail or no the update_2. This run inside the first transaction, but is something different of your model after_commit callback.

Comment: I don't know where the transaction starts and ends. Imagine there's 15 callbacks chain some of which can start the transaction and there a shared piece of code you want to be executed after transaction is completed

Answer (score -2):

As I understand your question you want to define code that should be run after the transaction inside a transation? But you do not want to run it straight away?

If this is the case it can be achieved with a `proc`. Info about [procs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Proc.html).

So the code would be something like:

```
 no_exceptions = true
 ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
   do_this
   after_code = Proc.new do |no_e|
     # Code defining how to act no_e gives you info if exceptions where fired.
   end
   do_that
 rescue Exception => e
   no_exceptions = false
 end
 after_code.call(no_exceptions)
```

I hope this was what you where looking for.